# how to compare filesystem sizes with -h human-readable suffixes in unix

Tags: linux, filesystems, memory, size

I am taking input as memory ex. 10M or 50G  or 50 K

and I want to check this much size available in file system.
for that I'm using `df -h` command

```
df -Ph . | awk 'NR==2 {print $4}'
```

I am getting 140M and my input may vary like 10k , 10M and 10G

EX:

my input is 20G and available memory in filesystem is 140M

So now how can I compare these two sizes (50G >140M ?) and echo output result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

convert your available and input values to Kb and compare it..

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "Enter the value ( value should end with G/M/K): "
read DISK_VALUE

AVAILABLE_SPACE=$(df -h . | awk 'NR==2{print $4}')
AVAILABLE_SPACE_IN_KB=$(echo "${AVAILABLE_SPACE}" | awk '/M$/{print ($0+0)*1024}/G$/{print ($0+0)*1024*1024}/K$/{print $0+0}')
COMPARE_VALUE_IN_KB=$(echo "${DISK_VALUE}" | awk '/M$/{print ($0+0)*1024}/G$/{print ($0+0)*1024*1024}/K$/{print $0+0}')

echo "AVAILABLE_SPACE_IN_KB : ${AVAILABLE_SPACE_IN_KB}"
echo "COMPARE_VALUE_IN_KB : ${COMPARE_VALUE_IN_KB}"

if [ "${AVAILABLE_SPACE_IN_KB}" -lt "${COMPARE_VALUE_IN_KB}" ]
then
        echo "Available space (${AVAILABLE_SPACE}) is lesser than Given Value (${DISK_VALUE})"
else
        echo "Available space (${AVAILABLE_SPACE}) is greater than Given Value (${DISK_VALUE})"
fi

$ bash a.sh
Enter the value : 1000K
AVAILABLE_SPACE_IN_KB : 100
COMPARE_VALUE_IN_KB : 1000
Available space (100K) is lesser than Given Value (1000K)

$ bash a.sh
Enter the value : 101M
AVAILABLE_SPACE_IN_KB : 102400
COMPARE_VALUE_IN_KB : 103424
Available space (100M) is lesser than Given Value (101M)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use -h with sort

Example

```
$cat <<EOF | sort -h
50G 
140M 
10M
50K
EOF
```

Result :

```
50K
10M
140M 
50G
```

Explanation:

-h, --human-numeric-sort, compare human readable numbers (e.g., 2K 1G)

Or inside a bash :

```
compare()
{
cat <<EOF | sort -h
$1
$2
EOF
}

set $(compare 50G 140M)
echo "$1 <= $2"
```

Result:

```
140M <= 50G
```

Another way to write compare :

```
compare()
{
echo -e "$1 \0 $2" | sort -zh
}
```

Comment: its good. but can u explain how it is working.

Comment: @saidesh. A pipe connects cat and sort. Cat produce data to sort. $( cmd ) executes a command. And set affect to $1 .. $n  the result of $( cmd ).